# How to find GCD for a list of (1:n) numbers in R

Tags: r, greatest-common-divisor

How to find GCD for a list of (1:n) numbers in R ?

```
GCD=function(a, b){
m=min(a, b)
while(a%%m>0|b%%m>0){m=m-1}
return(m)}
```

Here is my code to find GCD for two integers, how can I modify it to find GCD for a list of numbers from 1 to n  without too much changes on my original code?
Thankyou very much !

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `any` function:

```
GCD <- function(x) {
  m = min(x)
  
  while (any(x %% m > 0)){
    m = m - 1
  }
  
  return(m)
}

GCD(c(12, 24, 28, 36, 200))
# [1] 4

GCD(c(6, 24, 28, 36, 200))
# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define function `gcd` based on `GCD` like below

```
gcd <- function(...) Reduce(GCD,list(...))
```

and you can try

```
> gcd(6, 24, 28, 36, 200)
[1] 2
```

---

If you want a recursion for `GCD` (your origin answer has a slow convergence due to `m <- m -1`), you can try

```
GCD <- function(...) {
    args <- c(...)
    if (length(args) == 2) {
        if (args[2] == 0) {
            return(args[1])
        } else {
            return(Recall(args[2], args[1] %% args[2]))
        }
    }
    Recall(args[1], Recall(args[-1]))
}
```

such that

```
> GCD(6, 24, 28, 36, 200)
[1] 2

> GCD(12, 24, 28, 36, 200)
[1] 4
```